# MySQL Stored Procedure Conditional Statement

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, stored-functions

Can anyone help me on how could I have an conditional statement on the MySQL stored procedure?

I have this as sample query,

If my stored procedure parameter `isFirstTask = true` then I will use `LEFT JOIN` else I will use `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT *
FROM jobdetails jd
INNER JOIN taskslogs tl ON jd.jobID = tl.jobid;
```

The question is how could change the `INNER JOIN` into `LEFT JOIN` without repeating the whole query just to replace one word. Assuming that my query is bulk. Is it possible? Some idea please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM jobdetails jd
      LEFT JOIN taskslogs tl ON jd.jobID=tl.jobid
WHERE IF(isFirstTask = TRUE, TRUE, tl.jobid IS NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can build the query as a string inside the stored procedure. While building the query, check the value of your parameter and decide which JOIN to use. Hope this helps.